# I get an error while trying to call IAudioClient::GetService()

Tags: c++, windows

I get these errors when I'm trying to compile the program:

[image]

I can get rid of error LNK2001 by using `__uuidof(IChannelAudioVolume)`, but in the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/audioclient/nf-audioclient-iaudioclient-getservice) it says I should be able to use `IID_IChannelAudioVolume`.

This is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <Windows.h>
#include <Audioclient.h>
#include <mmdeviceapi.h>
#include <endpointvolume.h>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    //defining valiables
    HRESULT hr;
    UINT32 Channel_count = 0;
    IAudioClient* aClient = nullptr;
    IChannelAudioVolume* pAudioControls = nullptr;

    aClient->IAudioClient::GetService(IID_IChannelAudioVolume, (void**)pAudioControls);

    //hr = pAudioControls->GetChannelCount(&Channel_count);

    delete aClient;
    delete pAudioControls;
    return 0;
}
```

**edit**:

So i found, that i need to call Initialize() func, but it doesn't change anything. I also tried looking it up, but i don't know what should my *aClient* be (what other functions should i call to change it). Also [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LeQyJ.png) is Output picture with error.

**The same error with aClient beeing nullptr occurs*

Code:

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <Audioclient.h>
#include <mmdeviceapi.h>
#include <endpointvolume.h>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    //defining valiables
    HRESULT hr;
    UINT32 Channel_count = 0;
    IAudioClient* aClient = nullptr;
    IChannelAudioVolume* pAudioControls = nullptr;
    WAVEFORMATEX *wf = nullptr;


    hr = aClient->Initialize(AUDCLNT_SHAREMODE_SHARED, 0, 10000, 0, wf, NULL);
    
    if (!SUCCEEDED(hr)) {
        cout << "Error while initializing\n";
        return -1;
    }
    cout << "Initialization successfull\n";
    



    aClient->IAudioClient::GetService(__uuidof(IChannelAudioVolume), (void**)pAudioControls);

    pAudioControls->GetChannelCount(&Channel_count);


    aClient->Release();
    pAudioControls->Release();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Note: Images of code and error messages (and generally anything text) are among the most efficient ways to ensure your question is unfavorably received. Reproduce the errors in text. In your case the IDE looks like Visual Studio, so switch to the Output Tab where the program errors are in full and unvarnished text. Cut and paste the text from there. As an added bonus the full build output often contains information left out of the summary given in the Error List and helps crack the case. I don't think I've bothered looking at the Error list in years.

Comment: your code looks nothing like the samples in the doc, ie https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/coreaudio/capturing-a-stream, and calling `aClient->Anything` with `aClient = nullptr` will fail

Comment: `aClient->IAudioClient::GetService` overrides virtual function lookup, which is not what you want.